# Variational formulation of an elliptic pde

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, calculus-of-variations

Let $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $a\in(-1,1)$, what is the variational formulation of the following problem:
$$ \text{div}(y^a\nabla_{x,y}V)=0,\quad\text{on }\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty),$$
$$ V(x,0)=f(x),\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,?$$
Is true that the solution is a minimum of the energy:
$$ [U]_a=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty)}y^a|\nabla U|^2\,dx\,dy?$$
What functional space i have to use? I have no idea on how to proceed. I have think that i have to use the completion of $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,\infty))$ under the norm:
$[\cdot]_a^{1/2}$, but $[\cdot]_a^{1/2}$ not seems to be a norm.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is the class $\mathcal W$ of weakly differentiable functions $u$ such that

- $[u]_a$ is finite,
- $u(\cdot, y)$ is in $L^2(\mathbb R^n \times (0, y_0))$ for some (or, equivalently, for all) $y_0$.

This becomes a Hilbert space when equipped with norm $$[u] + \|u(\cdot, 0)\|_2. $$ Note that one can prove that $u(\cdot, y)$ depends continuously on $y \in [0, \infty)$ with respect to the $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ norm (after a modification of $u$ on a set of zero Lebesgue measure), so the above definition makes sense.

This is written with all details (but in a much greater generality) in my paper with Jacek Mucha:

- M. Kwaśnicki, J. Mucha, *Extension technique for complete Bernstein functions of the Laplace operator*, J. Evol. Equ. 18(3) (2018): 1341–1379, [DOI:10.1007/s00028-018-0444-4](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00028-018-0444-4).

There are certainly better references that focus specifically on the extension technique for fractional powers of the Laplace operator.

Comment: How i can prove that $u(\cdot,y)$ is continuous form $[0,\infty)$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: This is written in Section 4.1 in the paper cited above.

Comment: In section 4.1 there is write is "easily sees that the Bochner integral $\int_0^S\partial_su(s,\cdot)\,ds=u_0+u(S,0)$ for constant function $u_0\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ", i don't understand the existence of such $u_0$. Maybe i can use fundamental theorem of calculus for Bochner integral ? But i can't prove $u\in W^{1,2}((0,\infty),L^2(\mathbb{R}^n))$. Can you give me more details please?

Comment: I have another question: is true that $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty)$ is a dense subset of the class $\mathcal{W}$ wrt the norm $[u]_a+||u(\cdot,0)||_2$? If yes, how i can prove this fact?

Comment: @inoc: Write $w(s) = \int_0^S \partial_s u(s) ds - u(s)$. Then $w$ is weakly differentiable and $\partial_s w = 0$ almost everywhere, and therefore $w(s)$ is constant. Now just define $u_0 = w(s)$ (as this does not depend on $s$).

Comment: Next, $u$ need not be in $W^{1,2}$ on the half-space, as someone pointed out to you in one of your other questions.

Comment: Finally, I doubt that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n \times (0,\infty))$ is dense in $\mathcal W$: all functions in the former class have zero trace on the boundary. On the other hand, $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n \times [0, \infty))$ seems to be dense in $\mathcal W$ by the standard mollify-and-cutoff argument.

Comment: What does you mean for standard mollify-and-cutoff argument? Can you give a little bit of details please?

Comment: Multiply $u$ by your favourite cutoff and convolve with your favourite mollifier to get a smooth, compactly supported approximation to $u$. This works in the usual Sobolev spaces, so it should work for $\cal W$, too. Get the "Hitchhiker's guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces" if you need references or details (this may be way too general for your needs, but off the top of my head I do not know a better source).

Comment: I have to consider cutoff function and mollifier on what domain to get compact support in $\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,\infty)$? in $\mathbb{R}^n\times (0,\infty)$?

Comment: I would start by extending $u$ to all of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ so that, say, $u(x,y) = u(0,y)$ whenever $y < 0$. Sorry for not making this clear.

Comment: I don’t understand your hints.